# Does Docker Images automatically store in docker hub?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, linux-containers

I am planning to customise Centos image with some add-ons (like Apache web server etc). Once done , I want it to be stored locally. I don't want it to be stored on hub at any cost.
If I want to share with my peers, I would like to export and share.
My question here is, when I customise my image, does it automatically move to docker hub or will it be local ? Also want to know how safe it is.

Comment: No, a docker image would only share on docker hub account if you push it to account and you didn't integrate an image to any repository (github / bitbucket or similar other) account.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Docker images will not be stored in any registry/repository unless you specifically push it to a hub. Using a registry is as safe as the provider's security. If you wanted, you can also create your own, local registry, which would be useful for version control for yourself, but wouldn't be accessible to anyone else.